# How to display google coordinates

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I want to  display the location base on the value that I get from getLocation but all I get is a blue screen if I assign for example
 this.lat=25.7777, this.lng=26,777; but it does not if a did like this  this.lat=this.LAT; this.lng=this.LNG; and it works fine one last thing l would like to mention that the datatype in the database is double and I have tried testing a text as well

```
  lat:number;
  lng:number;
  LAT:any;
  LNG:any;

  constructor(public dataservice:DataService,private geolocation: Geolocation) {
this.dataservice.getLocation(ID)
  .subscribe(data =>{this.LAT = data[0].lat,
    this.LNG=data[0].lng

     this.lat=this.LAT;
     this.lng=this.LNG;


  });
```

.html

```
  <agm-map [latitude]="lat"[longitude]="lng" [zoom]="10"
      [zoomControl]="true">
  <agm-marker  [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Allow-Control-Allow-Origin in configuring your apache or Node.js server. rather then chrome plugin.

make changes in your server such that add that required header in response.

Comment: I did  Allow-Control-Allow-Origin in my server if you mean that I don't get any data from the getLocation request I did get the data I I output them on the console to make sure they are correct